# Submitting multiple list items in an asp.net MVC 5 view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an asp.net MVC5 view of survey questions pulled from the database. I added an extra textbox field to track the weights of the response selected from the drop down list. For each response selected, the weight is updated to reflect the value of item selected. Upon submission, I want to submit the question Ids and also the corresponding weights of their responses.  Below is the view which has the questions

```
@model IEnumerable<WorkPlaceBullyApp.Models.Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey Questions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Survey Questions</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any Questions yet!.</p>
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Question", "New", "Question", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Survey Questions</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Score: <span class="wwSum">0</span></li>
                        <li><span class="fBack">No Data Yet!</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <p>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover ques-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Questions</td>
                            <td>Category</td>
                            <td>Response</td>
                            <td>Weight</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @foreach (var question in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBox(@question.Id.ToString(), false, new { @class = "ckb", Id = question.Id, @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink(@question.SurveyQuestion, "Edit", "Question", new { id = @question.Id }, null)
                                @*@question.SurveyQuestion*@
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @question.QuestionCategory.QuestionCat
                            </td>
                            @if (@question.QResponseCategory.Id == 1)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ResponseId, "Select Response", new { @class = "form-control sel" })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="Weight" name="__Weight" class="form-control myValu" value="" readonly />
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SurveyResponse", "Response", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "SubmitResponses" })*@

        <input type="button" id="SubmitResponses" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </p>
}
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".sel").change(function (e) {
                var wSum = 0;
                $(this).closest("td").next().find("input").val(this.value);
                //$("input#Weight").each(function (e) {
                //    var itemVal = $(this).val() == "" ? 0 : $(this).val();
                //    if (itemVal !== null) {
                //        $('.ckb').each(function () {
                //            this.checked = true;
                //        });
                //    } else {
                //        $('.ckb').each(function () {
                //            this.checked = false;
                //        });
                //    }
                //    wSum += parseInt(itemVal);
                //});

                $(".ques-table tbody tr").each(function (e) {
                    var check = $(this).find(":checkbox:eq(0)");
                    var score = $(this).find(".myValu").val();
                    if (score != "") check["0"].checked = true;

                    var select = $(this).find("#Weight").val();
                    var itemVal = select == "" ? 0 : select;
                    wSum += parseInt(itemVal);
                });

                $("#SubmitResponses").click(function () {
                    checkedIds = $(".ckb").filter(":checked").map(function () { return this.id; });
                    weights = $(this).find(":value").val().map(function () { return this.val(); });

                    // console.log(weights); weights throws errors

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("SurveyResponse", "Response")",
                        traditional: true,
                        data: { Ids: checkedIds.toArray(), Weights: weight.toArray(), UserId: "@ViewBag.UserId" }
                    });
                });

                if (wSum < 51) {
                    $(".fBack").text("You don't yet understand what is needed to create a culture of dignity and respect");
                }
                if (wSum >= 51) {
                    $(".fBack").text("You have some awareness of requirements but significant efforts is still needed");
                }
                if (wSum >= 76) {
                    $(".fBack").text("You have reasonable skills in creating a culture of dignity and respect");
                }
                if (wSum >= 100) {
                    $(".fBack").text("You have excellent skill in creating a culture of dignity and respect.");
                }
                $(".wwSum").text(wSum);
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

I couldn't get the weight scores into list as it is throwing errors.

Secondly when I uncommented the

```
weights = $(this).find(":value").val().map(function () { return this.val(); });
```

and put some test values in my controller

```
    public ActionResult SurveyResponse(List<int> Ids, List<int> Weights, int UserId)
    {
        SurveyResponse myResponse = new SurveyResponse();
        foreach (var item in Ids)
        {             
            myResponse.UserId = 3;
            myResponse.QuestionId = 1;
            myResponse.Weight = 1;
            myResponse.Date = DateTime.Now;

            _context.SurveyResponse.Add(myResponse);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I couldn't submit the responses. The image below is the rendered view (UI) to the survey questions

[image]
[image]

From the above image...whenever a participant picks a response from the dropdownlist, it will populate the weights with the appropriate score and at the same time check the corresponding checkbox in the row. So the checked value is mearnt to pick the question ID and the weights has the values to the scores. Challenge is how to get this various values, the question ID and the associated score into the database.

Comment: In jquery, are you able to get values in `weights` variable?

Comment: You do not even use the `Weights` value in your POST method so what is the point? And you would be posting back only the values of the checked checkboxes but all weights so you would have not idea of what belongs to what. Its unclear what your trying to do here, and even why your using ajax. Very little of your view code makes sense (and you have a lot of invalid html)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: getting the weights values in query was throwing errors... So tested it without the weights... It was hitting the controller and not submitting correct values to the database.

Comment: @jignesh patel: No... I'm not getting values in the weights variable but getting in the scores variable

Comment: What do you want to use the values for. And your `List<int> Ids` will not be populated correctly either. As I noted there are multiple problems with your code but its impossible to understand what your trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Please What are the problems with my Html? I will add the rendered view as an image and give proper explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't need to see any images, but an explanation is necessary. And also why your using ajax

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I'm using Ajax because I don't have sufficient knowledge to do the same thing in asp.net MVC. If you had a way this could be archieved...kindly help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150612/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-guzzyman).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to get value of `weights`.

```
Just change your code to get the value of `weights`. 

$("#SubmitResponses").click(function () {
     var checkedIds = [];
     var weights = [];

     $('table > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")){
            checkedIds.push($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('Id'));
            weights.push($(this).find('select').val());
        }
     });

     // console.log(weights); weights throws errors

     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "@Url.Action("SurveyResponse", "Response")",
           traditional: true,
           data: { Ids: checkedIds.toArray(), Weights: weight.toArray(),UserId: "@ViewBag.UserId" }
     });
});
```